# How to show the first x characthers of a Django model field in self representation

Tags: django-models

How can I use the first, let's say 10 characters of a field in the string representation of a Django model entry?
If I simply use `{self.Post}` I get the whole thing that might be too long. I tried to use `{self.Post,10}` but that doesn't really fly.

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    Poster = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Poster")
    PostCreated = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, null=True, verbose_name="Post created")
    Post = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name="Post")
    PostEdited = models.BooleanField(
        default=False, verbose_name="Has been edited")
    PostHasComments = models.BooleanField(
        default=False, verbose_name="Has comments")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.Post} by {self.Poster}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Posts"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *slice* the post, with:

```
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.Post[:10]} by {self.Poster}'
```